# Can I manually verify an email/password account on firebase?

Tags: swift, email, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a demo account for my app, so that I can submit it to the iOS App Store. The app requires that your email be verified before you can use it. However, the verification emails are not coming into my demo@xxx.xxx inbox, and so I cannot verify the account. Is there any way I can manually set that firebase account as verified?
Thanks

Answer (score 14):

**This works as a cloud function.**

I add the userid as a key to a child called force with any value and it triggers this function that authenticates the email.

you also must include

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

cloud function

```
  exports.forceQue = functions.database.ref('/force/{uid}').onWrite((data,context) => {

  if (!data.after.exists()) {
      return false;
  }

  const uid = context.params.uid;

        admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {emailVerified: true});
        return true;
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

Firebase Authentication doesn't have an API to set the verification status of an email address.

The Firebase Admin SDK (which should only be run on a trusted environment, such as a machine you control) *can* set this flag. See [this documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) for an example.

But unless you're submitting apps on behalf of the users of your app, shouldn't the email address just be your usual (real) mail address?

Comment: I would prefer not to put my personal email address as the account used by apple to verify the application.

Comment: Ah.... I think I get it now. I don't think there is a way to fake verification. But you could hard-code the demo@xxx.xxx email address in your security rules.

Comment: Somebody claims that their spam filter is blocking the verify step, so looking for a workaround to flag their account as verified.

Comment: You can nowadays set the flag through the Firebase Admin SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Answer (score -2):

if you mean adding an email on your firbase to have access as a user to the app then you can do that as per the picture[image]

Comment: No, this doesn't make the email address approved